# R Multiply second dimension of 3D Array by a Vector for each of the 3rd dimension

Tags: arrays, r

When trying to multiply the first dimension of an array by each index of a vector by the second dimension, my array is converted to a matrix and things get squirrelly.  I can only do the proper multiplication long-hand.

What a mouth full...

It's easier to explain with code...

```
Arr <- array(runif(10*5*3), dim = c(10,5,3))
dim(Arr)
Vect <- c(1:5)

Arr[,1,1] <- Arr[,1,1]*Vect[1]
Arr[,1,2] <- Arr[,1,2]*Vect[1]
Arr[,1,3] <- Arr[,1,3]*Vect[1]

Arr[,2,1] <- Arr[,2,1]*Vect[2]
Arr[,2,2] <- Arr[,2,2]*Vect[2]
Arr[,2,3] <- Arr[,2,3]*Vect[2]

Arr[,3,1] <- Arr[,3,1]*Vect[3]
Arr[,3,2] <- Arr[,3,2]*Vect[3]
Arr[,3,3] <- Arr[,3,3]*Vect[3]

Arr[,4,1] <- Arr[,4,1]*Vect[4]
Arr[,4,2] <- Arr[,4,2]*Vect[4]
Arr[,4,3] <- Arr[,4,3]*Vect[4]

Arr[,5,1] <- Arr[,5,1]*Vect[5]
Arr[,5,2] <- Arr[,5,2]*Vect[5]
Arr[,5,3] <- Arr[,5,3]*Vect[5]
```

How do I clean this up to be one command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast `Vect` into an array first, then element multiply:

```
varr <- aperm(array(Vect, dim = c(5L, 10L, 3L)), perm = c(2L, 1L, 3L))

Arr <- varr * Arr
```

(of course we don't need to store `varr` if you want this in one command)

(also, turns out this is basically what `sweep` does under the hood...)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
sweep(Arr,2,Vect,FUN="*")
```

Comment: The manual page for `sweep` is far from illuminating (I still don't know what is meant by `STATS` is "the summary statistic which is to be swept out"), but you've illuminated its use wonderfully here! Earmark this for SO Dox (if that ever comes to be...)

Answer (score 1):

The `aaply()` function from the [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) package does exactly what you're looking for. It can operate on arrays of any dimension and split them however you like. In this case you're splitting by rows so:

```
library(plyr)
Arr2 <- aaply(Arr, 1, function(x,y){x*y}, Vect)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also replicate the 'Vect' and multiply with 'Arr'.  The `col` is a convenient function that gives the numeric index of columns.

```
res1 <- Arr * Vect[col(Arr[,,1])]
```

Or we explicitly do the `rep`

```
res2 <- Arr* rep(Vect, each=dim(Arr)[1])
identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```